# Angular Pipe - reset checkbox when other options pipe filters selected

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-pipe

I have a list of courses which are displayed through a filterable *ngFor using a filtercourses pipe. I have 5 buttons at the top that trigger the filter to filter the course, 1 for all courses and 4 for specific course categories. The courses data has a property that says it is completed or not. I have added a checkbox to also filter the completed courses.

[image]

Problem 1: This works fine on the initial checking but when I uncheck it it does not return the list to unfiltered courses.

Problem 2: The checkbox needs to uncheck every time a button with the other filters are clicked. (I am hoping this can be changed from the template itself using a template reference)

Pipe

```
@Pipe({
name: 'filtercourses'
})
export class FiltercoursesPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: any[], courseCategory: string): any {    
  if(courseCategory === 'all'){ return items } 
  else if (courseCategory === 'completed') {
    console.log(courseCategory)
    return items.filter(item => {
      return item.completed === true;
    });
  } else    
  return items.filter(item =>{   
    return item.courseCategory === courseCategory;    
  });    return null;
}

}
```

Template

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div class="column is-10 grid-center mblg">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <button class="button is-small is-success mrmd" (click)="filterBy='all'">All</button>

            <button class="button is-small is-info mrmd" (click)="filterBy='Mandatory & Compliance'">Mandatory &
                        Compliance</button>

            <button class="button is-small is-info mrmd" (click)="filterBy='Leadership & Management'">Leadership
                        & Management</button>

            <button class="button is-small is-info mrmd" (click)="filterBy='Personal Effectiveness'">Personal
                        Effectiveness</button>

            <button class="button is-small is-info mrmd" (click)="filterBy='Business Skills'">Business
                        Skills</button>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <input id="switchColorSuccess" type="checkbox" name="switchColorSuccess" class="switch is-success"
                        checked="checked" (change)="filterBy='completed'">
            <label for="switchColorSuccess">Completed</label>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <li *ngFor="let course of courses | filtercourses:filterBy">
            <h3>{{course.courseName}}</h3>
            <h4>{{course.courseCategory}}</h4>
            <h5 *ngIf="course.completed" style="color: green">COURSE COMPLETED</h5>
            <img src="{{course.courseImg}}" class="img" width="200"/>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

I have created this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-template-reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **first issue** you can introduce a toggle method that alternates between 'all' and 'completed'

.html

```
<div class="field">
    <input #switchColorSuccess type="checkbox" name="switchColorSuccess" 
           class="switch is-success"
           (change)="toggle()">
    <label for="switchColorSuccess">Completed</label>
</div>
```

.ts (You will need a reference of the input for this to work which is explained below)

```
toggle() {
  if (this.switchColorSuccess.nativeElement.checked) {
    this.filterBy = "completed";
  } else {
    this.filterBy = "all";
  }
}
```

For the **second issue** you can use the `@ViewChild` to get a reference of the input by id. Now you can set it to false everytime it is invoked. For eg:

.html

```
<!-- button -->
<button class="button is-small is-success mrmd" (click)="invokeByFilter('all')">All</button>

<!-- checkbox -->
<div class="field">
    <input #switchColorSuccess type="checkbox" name="switchColorSuccess" 
           class="switch is-success"
           (change)="toggle()">
    <label for="switchColorSuccess">Completed</label>
</div>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild("switchColorSuccess", { static: false }) switchColorSuccess: ElementRef;

invokeByFilter(input:string) {
   this.switchColorSuccess.nativeElement.checked = false;
   this.filterBy = input;
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-template-reset-ezkpaj) is the working stackblitz demo which was forked from yours.

Comment: Thanks for the first point. But filterBy is passed around the template and is never called from the component. There is no ngModel for filterBy it is only passed into the pipe as a variable. I think that is the case. I will look into your second point. Thanks!

Comment: You are an absolute star! Thank you very much!